# Program keeps throwing error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been checking all of my code for hours now and i just can't seem to find tthe error in here
it keeps throwing **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class entitiys.Image**

my controller looks like this:

```
package imageSearcher;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AppController {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppController.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

this is what the Image entity looks like:

```
package entitiys;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "image")     
public class Image {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name= "imageURL")
    public String imageURL;

}
```

The image mapping looks as following

```
package imageSearcher;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import entitiys.Image;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
public class ImageController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ImageRepository imageRep;
    
    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public Iterable<Image> index() {
        return imageRep.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/all/URL")
    public Iterable<String> AllURL() {
        return imageRep.findAllURL();
    }

}
```

the imahe CrudRepository looks like this:

```
package imageSearcher;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import entitiys.Image;

@Repository
public interface ImageRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, Integer>{
    
    @Query(value = "select * from Image", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable<Image> findAll();
    
    @Query(value = "select Image.imageURL from Image", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable<String> findAllURL();

}
```

this is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is the application.properties:

```
server.port=91
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gip2021
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_startegy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I have no clue of what is wrong here i hope someone can help me because this is for my final project and even my Teacher can't see the issue

also here is the database script for if you need it:

```
create table Image(
    id integer unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    imageURL varchar(255)
);

insert into image (imageURL) values
    ("test"),
    ("test2");
```

for anyone wanting the git repo:
https://github.com/michiel2003/GIP2021.git

Comment: I think entity Image is outside the package of your main SpringBoot starter class "AppController.java", try putting Image entity class in the same package as your main class or move spring boot starter class outside under java.

Comment: Wow thanks that actually worked i'm so happy now

Comment: Perfect........

Answer (score 1):

Just moved everything to the same package and it worked my teacher told me to put the entitiys in a different package and that's not what you are supposed to do

Comment: "not what you are supposed to do" is not true, it's just that if you use a different package, you need to explicitly tell that to Spring

Answer (score 0):

The from spring boot documentation for @SpringBootApplication :

> Many Spring Boot developers always have their main class annotated
> with @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan.
> Since these annotations are so frequently used together (especially if
> you follow the best practices above), Spring Boot provides a
> convenient @SpringBootApplication alternative.
> The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using
> @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their
> default attributes: [...]

and @ComponentScan:

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the
> package of the class that declares this annotation.

So only imageSearcher package is being scanned. You need to rearrange you packages or change @SpringBootApplication annotation to

> @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"imageSearcher","entitiys"})

EDIT:
If your teacher told you to move it to different package maybe he wanted you to make workaround for just like I proposed

Answer (score 0):

created the pull request: https://github.com/michiel2003/GIP2021/pull/1 that will fix the bug, you can simply merge it :)

agreeing with every points that have already been mentioned above regarding [@ComponentScan](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning) and adding additional things that caught my eyes:

- `this bug` can be easily reproduced by adding a dummy `loadContext` test, this test will be generated when you start bootstrapping a spring boot application by using [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/), which is always the best way to start `spring booting`
- I know test experience has always been treated as an overhead for junior developers, but it is worth it if you want to go down the road to a senior :)
- when looking into your git histories: please do not simply delete getter and setters just because they look like template code, if you feel comfortable you can try adding [lombok](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok)